# How can I force Flask to change version? (reports 0.12.2 even after specifying 1.0.2)

Tags: python, pip

When I run

```
flask --version
```

in the terminal, flask reports: Flask 0.12.2

I am having issues with the flask tutorial and suspect this may be the cause.

I have run

```
pip uninstall flask
```

and

```
pip install Flask==1.0.2
```

but flask still tells me its version is 0.12.2

So how can I force Flask to change version?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the referenced question used to close this question - this is about forcing a version, not an initial install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the --force-reinstall flag. To updgrade or downgrade a package to a specific version you should use the --force-reinstall flag.
The command below should work.

```
pip install --force-reinstall flask==1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this it will help you to reinstall the flask with the newly provided version. --force-reinstall tag works somehow in a way that it first removes the old package and then on that install the new package with the provided version:

```
pip install --force-reinstall Flask==1.0.2
```

or

```
pip install -Iv Flask==1.0.2
```

the -Iv will ask pip to ignore the last installed version and install a new version.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. It still reports the same version (0.12.2)

Comment: @George can you upload your pip freeze output?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall <packagename>`

`--upgrade` and `--force-reinstall` ensures reinstallation

`--no-deps` avoids reinstalling dependencies